# SQL: difference of 2 columns in a new column

Tags: sql, mariadb, calculated-columns, mariasql

I have the following SQL table, with a `positive` column and a `negative` column, both `int`s.

```
positive    negative
----------------------
5           3
3           1
10          7
```

How can I create a third column, e.g. `total` that is equal to `positive - negative`. Also, I would like the `total` column to be updated every time an element of the `positive` or `negative` column changes.

How can I do this in SQL?

**Edit:** I am using MariaDB

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you be more specific, e.g. SqlServer, MySql, Oracle etc please?

Comment: You can use triggers if you really need this denormalisation, though i doubt it makes much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of computed column as described below

you can create table as

```
create table table_name ( positive int, negitive int, difference as positive-negitive)
```

then after creating, if you enter values as

```
insert into table_name values(3,2)
```

--no need to enter third column it is called as computed column.

then after inserting the difference will be present in the third column "difference"

---

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual computed column as explained here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/

```
create table table1
(
    positive   int not null,
    negative   int not null,
    difference int as (positive - negative) virtual
);
```